# inetOrgPerson with member or memberOf?

Tags: ldap, openldap

### What works

Suppose I have `inetOrgPerson`s in `ou=people,dc=example,dc=com`. Example:

```
dn: cn=John Doe,ou=people,dc=example,dc=com
objectClass: inetOrgPerson (structural)
objectClass: person (structural)
objectClass: top (abstract)
cn: John Doe
sn: Doe
givenName: John
mail: john.doe@example.com
uid: john.doe
```

In addition I have several `organization`s:

```
dn: o=foo,dc=example,dc=com
objectClass: organization (structural)
objectClass:top (abstract)
o: foo

dn: o=bar,dc=example,dc=com
objectClass: organization (structural)
objectClass:top (abstract)
o: bar
```

For each `organization` there is a `groupOfNames`:

```
dn: cn=users,o=foo,dc=example,dc=com
objectClass:groupOfNames (structural)
cn: users
member: cn=John Doe,ou=people,dc=example,dc=com

dn: cn=users,o=bar,dc=example,dc=com
objectClass:groupOfNames (structural)
cn: users
```

As you can see, `cn=John Doe,ou=people,dc=example,dc=com` is listed as a `member` of `cn=users,o=foo,dc=example,dc=com` but not of `dn: cn=users,o=bar,dc=example,dc=com`.

### Problem

I want to note membership at the `inetOrgPerson`s, too.

`memberOf` is not in the schemas I currently use for a user. Is there any schema available that provides `memberOf`?

`member` is part of `groupOfNames` but this `objectClass` conflicts with `inetOrgPerson`:

```
[LDAP: error code 65 - invalid structural object class chain (inetOrgPerson/groupOfNames)]
```

### Question

How can I note the membership in `cn=users,o=foo,dc=example,dc=com` on `cn=John Doe,ou=people,dc=example,dc=com`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're using OpenLDAP you need to use the ['memberof'](http://linux.die.net/man/5/slapo-memberof) overlay, which maintains a real 'memberOf' attribute among the operational attributes.

Note that it won't affect memberships that already exist, only new ones from when you first load the overlay. See the OpenLDAP documentation.

Answer (score 3):

Depending on the server in use, `memberOf` might be a virtual attribute and would not be listed in the entry, but rather is generated by the server. Some other servers use `isMemberOf` instead of `memberOf`. `memberOf` or `isMemberOf` would be generated upon request by server.

One could search:

```
ldapsearch -h hostname -p port \
   -b dc=example,dc=com -s sub \
   '(memberOf=cn=users,o=foo,dc=example,dc=com)'
```

or

```
ldapsearch -h hostname -p port \
   -b dc=example,dc=com -s sub \
   '(isMemberOf=cn=users,o=foo,dc=example,dc=com)'
```

to get the distinguished names that are members of `cn=users,o=foo,dc=example,dc=com`.

To get the groups of which a known distinguished name is a member:

```
ldapsearch -h hostname -p port \
   -b dc=example,dc=com -s sub \
   '(cn=Joe User)' isMemberOf
```

or

```
ldapsearch -h hostname -p port \
   -b dc=example,dc=com -s sub \
   '(cn=Joe User)' memberOf
```

The object class violation occurs because `groupofNames` and `inetOrgPerson` are both structural object classes. Only one structural object class is permitted per object. **Some broken directory servers (DSEE for example) will allow multiple structural object classes per object, though**. In one of your examples it appears the `person` and `inetOrgPerson` are in the same object together, this is a different case because `inetOrgPerson` is a descendant of `person`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it helps me to understand more about LDAP :) OpenLDAP 2.3 seems not support these virtual attributes. Both `member` and `isMemberOf` return nothing in both kinds of searches.

Comment: I'm almost sure it does support one of those, it might be an overlay. Consult the OpenLDAP docs.